# Lambdas in Linq AST - why different behaviour?

Tags: linq, abstract-syntax-tree

Let's assume the following demo classes.

```
public class Foo {
    public int key1 {get; set;}
    public Foo(int _key1) {
        key1 = _key1;
    }
}
public class Bar {
    public int key2 {get; set;}
    public Bar(int _key2) {
        key2 = _key2;
    }
}
```

They are combined together in a simple Linq join.

```
Foo[]aSet = new Foo[3]{new Foo(1),new Foo(2),new Foo(3)};
Bar[]bSet = new Bar[3]{new Bar(1),new Bar(3),new Bar(5)};

Func<int,Func<Foo,bool>> VisibleLambda = w => x => x.key1 > w;
var pb = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Bar),"z");
var pf = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "y");
PropertyInfo BarId = typeof(Bar).GetProperty("key2");
PropertyInfo FooId = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("key1");
var eqexpr = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(pb, BarId), Expression.Property(pf, FooId));
var lambdaInt = Expression.Lambda<Func<Bar, bool>>(eqexpr, pb);
var InvisibleLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo,Func<Bar, bool>>>( lambdaInt,pf);

var query = from a in aSet.Where(VisibleLambda(1))
    from b in bSet.Where(InvisibleLambda.Compile()(a))
    select new Tuple<Foo,Bar>(a,b);
```

Now, the query is implemented through an extension

```
IQueryable<TElement> IQueryProvider.CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
{
    if (expression == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");

    return new ExpressionQueryImpl<TElement>(DataContextInfo, expression);
}
```

The details of the implementation are irrelevant: my question is only related to the expression derived from the IQueryable.
There are two lambdas: one ("visible") is generated as an argument of the expression with a NodeType `Quote` that is very easy to analyse, while the other one ("invisible") is generated as a second argument of the expression with "where" clause of  NodeType `Invoke` that is almost invisible in terms of its sql rendering. 
Why is that happening and is there a way to work-around and d-tour it?

Comment: You are speaking about `Expression`s but show samples with `Func`s. Please update your post accordingly, leaving only the relevant information presenting the case.

Comment: @IvanStoev Done, for the "invisible" LambdaExpression, the one that is more relevant, because it is the cause of the "issue"

Comment: Now I sort of see what you mean, but expressions that **return** funcs are quite strange, so I'm not surprised the query provider cannot use them. For instance, note that `Queryable.Where` expects `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, i.e. lambda that takes `T` parameter and returns `bool` (not `Func`!).

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev your first comment was valuable (sorry I can't upvote it). Your second comment is unclear. I mean the Where does expect what you have written, it is correct. But it is a *join* so a need a Func to input the parameter from the first table. But again, I'm trying to find a solution from reading the Expression. I already have the "working" code for the initial Func, but it was not clean due to the fact I was not using the Expression. Really, I need to form a join so I need two types T1 and T2, the two "tables" in join.

Comment: In the meantime, as far as my original issue is concerned - i.e., the idea to implement a generic `Join<T1, T2>(Func<T1, Expression<Func<T2, bool>>> OnCondition)` in the query provider - , I think I've found a proposed [solution](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/328#issuecomment-205356227)!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by the comments [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399600/lambdas-in-linq-ast-why-different-behaviour#comment60416153_36399600) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399600/lambdas-in-linq-ast-why-different-behaviour#comment60419863_36399600) of Ivan Stoev, the different behaviour, and in particular the problem in the sql generation, was due to different signature expected from the `Queryable.Where`

[Here](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/328#issuecomment-205643667) is the solution from Igor Tkachev, for anyone who would be interested.

Everything boils down to implementing the helpful extension, where one can leverage the **linq method** with the **appropriate signature**: i.e the `Queryable.GroupJoin` :-)

```
    static class ExpressionTestExtensions
{
    public class LeftJoinInfo<TOuter,TInner>
    {
        public TOuter Outer;
        public TInner Inner;
    }

    [ExpressionMethod("LeftJoinImpl")]
    public static IQueryable<LeftJoinInfo<TOuter,TInner>> LeftJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey>(
        this IQueryable<TOuter> outer,
        IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
        Expression<Func<TOuter, TKey>> outerKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> innerKeySelector)
    {
        return outer
            .GroupJoin(inner, outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, (o, gr) => new { o, gr })
            .SelectMany(t => t.gr.DefaultIfEmpty(), (o,i) => new LeftJoinInfo<TOuter,TInner> { Outer = o.o, Inner = i });
    }

    static Expression<Func<
        IQueryable<TOuter>,
        IEnumerable<TInner>,
        Expression<Func<TOuter,TKey>>,
        Expression<Func<TInner,TKey>>,
        IQueryable<LeftJoinInfo<TOuter,TInner>>>>
        LeftJoinImpl<TOuter, TInner, TKey>()
    {
        return (outer,inner,outerKeySelector,innerKeySelector) => outer
            .GroupJoin(inner, outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, (o, gr) => new { o, gr })
            .SelectMany(t => t.gr.DefaultIfEmpty(), (o,i) => new LeftJoinInfo<TOuter,TInner> { Outer = o.o, Inner = i });
    }

}
```

Having defined such an extension, my "generic join" will turn to

```
        static internal IQueryable<ExpressionTestExtensions.LeftJoinInfo<T2,T1>> NewJoin<T1, T2, TKey>(Expression<Func<T2, TKey>> outer, Expression<Func<T1, TKey>> inner)
        where T2: class
        where T1 : class
    {


        using (var db = new MyContext()) {

        var query = (from b in db.GetTable<T2>() select b).LeftJoin <T2,T1, TKey>((from f in db.GetTable<T1>() select f), outer, inner);


            return query;

        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the elegant use case simply becomes

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        //var queryList = Test.Join<Bar, Foo>(b => q => q.id == b.id);


        var queryList =  Test.NewJoin<Bar, Foo, int>(q => q.id, b => b.id);

        foreach (var telement in queryList)
        {
            var bar = telement.Inner as Bar;
            var element = telement.Outer as Foo;
            Console.WriteLine(element.id.ToString() + " " + element.FromDate.ToShortDateString() +" "
                              +bar.id.ToString() + " " + bar.Name
                             );
        }

        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```